# Using batch to look-up URLS - disrupting equation marks

Tags: parsing, batch-file

I've made one batch script that generates Google search URL's(www.google.no/search?q=%topic%) for me, and now I'm working on a script that will download the content on each of those URLs.
The problem is that the Google search URLs always contain an equation sign, which does not work well in the batch script.

My code for downloading URL contents:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
::it's better to use the delayed expansion, because then the special characters lose their "special" behaviour, even carets and percent signs.
SET localfolder=%~dp0
SET logger="%~dp0"\%~n0.log
echo %date% %time% %~n0
del %logger%

set urlPathOuput=%~dp0
set indexFile=index.html
cd %localfolder%
for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in (urls.txt) do (
    set "urlPath=%%~1" & call :download
)
goto :eof

:download
set urlPath=%urlPath: =%
set urlFileOutput=%urlPath%.log
set urlFileOutput=%urlFileOutput:/=_%
Echo %urlPath% "-"
wget "%urlpath%" > %localfolder%%urlFileOutput%
type %indexFile% > %localfolder%%urlFileOutput%
del %indexFile%
```

The result:

> c:\progge\Scripts\Web>set "urlPath=**www.google.no/search?q=painting "**
>
> c:\progge\Scripts\Web>set
>   urlFileOutput=**www.google.no/search?q=painting.log**
>
> c:\progge\Scripts\Web>set
>   urlFileOutput=**www.google.no_search?q=painting.log**
>
> c:\progge\Scripts\Web>Echo **www.google.no/search?q=painting** "-"
>   **www.google.no/search?q=painting** "-"
>
> c:\progge\Scripts\Web>wget **"www.google.no/search?q=painting" =painting.log** 1>**c:\progge\Scripts\Web\www.google.no_search?q**
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>
> c:\progge\Scripts\Web>type index.html **=painting.log** 1>**c:\progge\Scripts\Web\www.google.no_search?q**
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>
> c:\progge\Scripts\Web>del index.html
>   Could Not Find c:\progge\Scripts\Web\index.html

The URL must have the equation sign to work. 
How do I solve this?

Comment: `set "urlPath=%%~1" & call :download`.  Enclose the `"var=value"` pair in quotation marks to prevent their contents from being evaluated as batch syntax.  Also, `wget "%urlpath%"`.

Comment: and, as you remove the slashes from `urlFileOutput`, remove also the `?` that can not be used in a file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems ot a problem of the urlpath but of the `%localfolder%%urlFileOutput%` path.

`%localfolder%%urlFileOutput%` seems to be `c:\progge\Scripts\Web\www.google.no_search?q=painting.log`.

At first you need to enclose this with quotes

```
wget "%urlpath%" > "%localfolder%%urlFileOutput%"
```

But even then it will not work as it's not a legal path name.
It's not allowed to use characters like `?` in a path name.